# How to fail build on sufficient code coverage with jacoco

Tags: java, grails, gradle, jacoco

Actually we have a requirement in grails 3x application,application build get failed if code coverage is less than 50% with jacoco library. Here 50% is threshold amount for coverage and that will be configurable it could be 50% or 70% or any other amount.

`we have configured the configuration corresponding to jacoco in build.gradle file is as below-`

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

 jacocoTestReport{
        reports {
            xml.enabled false
            csv.enabled false
            html.destination "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/html"
        }
        executionData = files('build/jacoco/test.exec')
    }

test { finalizedBy jacocoTestReport }
```

`we got proper report but not able to set build failed if coverage not match our expectation`